# How can Latent Semantic Indexing be used for feature selection?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, feature-selection

I am studying some machine-learning and I have come across, in several places, that Latent Semantic Indexing may be used for feature selection. Can someone please provide a brief, simplified explanation of how this is done? Ideally both theoretically and in commented code. How does it differ from Principal Component Analysis?

What language it is written in doesn't really worry me, just that I can understand both code and theory.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do they do code implementations on the stats.stackexchange.com webpage? Apologies if this is the case, I thought StackOverflow would be more relevant given that I wanted a concrete implementation with an explanation of how it works :). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I am not sure if they cover implementation there, you will have to check the FAQ, but this is certainly not the place to ask to be provided with code

Comment: If you want an explanation of the statistical theory behing LSI, CrossValidated is the place to go. If you just want someone to provide code for you, StackOverflow is not the place to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LSA is conceptually similar to PCA, but is used in different settings.

The goal of **PCA** is to **transform data into new**, possibly **less-dimensional space.** For example, if you wanted to recognize faces and use 640x480 pixel images (i.e. vectors in 307200-dimensional space), you would probably try to reduce this space to something reasonable to both - make it computationally simpler and make data less noisy. PCA does exactly this: it "rotates" axes of your high-dimensional space and assigns "weight" to each of new axes, so that you can throw away least important of them.

**LSA**, on other hand, is used to **analyze semantic similarity** of words. It can't handle images, or bank data, or some other custom dataset. It is designed specifically for text processing, and works specifically with term-document matrices. Such matrices, however, are often considered too large, so they are reduced to form lower-rank matrices in a way very similar to PCA (both of them use [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)). Feature selection, though, is not performed here. Instead, what you get is **feature vector transformation**. SVD provides you with some transformation matrix (let's call it `S`), which, being multiplied by input vector `x` gives new vector `x'` in a smaller space with more important basis. 
This new basis is your new features. Though, they are not selected, but rather obtained by transforming old, larger basis.

For more details on LSA, as long as implementation tips, see [this](http://www.puffinwarellc.com/index.php/news-and-articles/articles/33.html?showall=1) article.